# Macro for adding spaces between merged words in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Today I had to edit a terrible text in Microsoft Word that have many paragraphs where all words are merged and text was impossible to read, nightmare :)
So, I thought, maybe there is a solution to this? 
I have this idea: 1) I go through text (or paragraph) placing cursor
between words which should be separated (i.e. loremipsum should become lorem ipsum).
2) macro remember all occasions when I placed cursor
3) macro inserts necessary spaces between words

But inserting a space when I place cursor also can be good.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: How will you distinguish between "hi there" and "hit here"?

Comment: That's why I described not automatic decision, it's only partially automatic. So question soudns like "How to make space appear on left mouse button click?" or "How to memorize all mouse clicks between words and then insert all necessary spaces between words at once?".

Comment: haha, second question is better I think)) thinks that I have answer for the first one.

Comment: I can envision perhaps one way to do this (nothing coded yet). Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? It's unhelpful to downvote without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

User939536, welcome to SO.  Before you build a full-fledged Add-In to Word, a good chunk of your functionality is already there.

If you go to **Word Options->Proofing->Autocorrect Options** (your version may have a different method), you can see the list of words to automatically replace with other words.  You can put your most commonly combined words here and let Word do the work for you.

The other route of course is to build an Add-In that will:

1. Have a database of commonly replaced words (probably a text file that's read on startup)
2. A search function to search the document
3. An interface to present the user with the choice to Replace or Skip.